# dynamic array without new operator?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

Since when is this valid syntax?
(works using g++ 4.6.3)
What should I search on to find further information about this (I'm used to new/delete)?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    size_t sz;
    std::cout<<"number?\n";
    std::cin>>sz;

    // This line
    float dynamic_arr[sz];

     //output the (uninitialized) value just to use the array.
     std::cout<<dynamic_arr[0]<<std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up "variable length arrays".

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason a `std::vector<float> dynamic_arr(sz);` would *not* work for you, and it isn't coming to me. Well, for `sz == 0` I suppose you'd be screwed, but so would your code be with a VLA, so.. yeah. nothing.

Comment: The code I'm looking at uses `__attribute__(aligned(32))` on the array for optimization against the IPP libraries; thus the author preferred a fixed size array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Varialbe length arrays (VLAs) are not standard C++, they are a compiler extension. You shouldn't use it if you want your code to be portable.

If you compile with the `-Wvla -Werror` flags, or `-Werror=vla`, your code will produce the error

> error: variable length array 'dynamic_arr' is used [-Werror=vla]

Comment: I'd go as far as saying that VLA's are just a bad idea in general (especially when created via user input), but that's not an absolute like your point is.

Comment: @EdS. I would have to agree. Code should be as standards compliant as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ does not support the variable length arrays (VLAs) of C99 and g++.

In standard C++ you can use e.g. **`std::vector`**, like this (your code modified):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    int sz;
    std::cout<<"number?\n";
    std::cin>>sz;

    // This line
    std::vector<double> dynamic_arr( sz );    // Initialized to zeroes.

     //output the value just to use the array.
     std::cout<<dynamic_arr[0]<<std::endl;
}
```

Also, for strings you can use **`std::basic_string`**, usually via the `typedef`s `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

Generally the main problem is just the dynamic size, as above, and then `std::vector` and `std::basic_string` do the job nicely. However, sometimes the problem is efficiency, how to do extremely efficient *stack allocation* of a dynamic size array. Many C and C++ implementations support the non-standard function **`alloca`** for that, but unfortunately they differ greatly in how it handles failures. As far as I know there is no commonly available library solution for that either. But happily, the main usage that I know of (even though as mentioned `alloca` is available for a number of platforms) has been for string encoding translation in Windows, and that's less and less relevant as time goes on and Windows programs more and more are pure Unicode-oriented.